# Determine which method to call based on array size and number of arguments

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm, overloading

I have a heavy computational algorithm which I must complete. In order to make it as efficient as possible, I've broken it into five methods based on the number of arguments. This allows me to economize as best as possible. That said, I don't want my user to be aware of that.

```
public AnalysisResult[] PerformAnalysis(double[] Inputs, double[] Outputs, int[][] Coefficients)
{
    AnalysisResult[] AR = new AnalysisResult[Coefficients.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < Coefficients.Length; i++)
        AR[i] = GetResults(Inputs, Outputs, /* Based on length of Coefficients[i]*/ );

    return AR;
}

private AnalysisResult GetResults(double[] Inputs, double[] Outputs, int A)
{
    // Do stuff
}

private AnalysisResult GetResults(double[] Inputs, double[] Outputs, int A, int B)
{
    // Do stuff
}

private AnalysisResult GetResults(double[] Inputs, double[] Outputs, int A, int B, int C)
{
    // Do stuff
}

private AnalysisResult GetResults(double[] Inputs, double[] Outputs, int A, int B, int C, int D)
{
    // Do stuff
}

private AnalysisResult GetResults(double[] Inputs, double[] Outputs, int A, int B, int C, int D, int E)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

As you can see, I want to have only one public method available to the user for calling the algorithm. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to determine which one of the private methods to call based on the length of the array that is passed in to `PerformAnalysis`?

Any suggestions?

My approach up to this point has been a switch statement based on the length of the array, but I assume there is a better approach.

```
public AnalysisResult[] PerformAnalysis(double[] Inputs, double[] Outputs, int[][] Coefficients)
{
    AnalysisResult[] AR = new AnalysisResult[Coefficients.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < Coefficients.Length; i++)
        switch (Coefficients[i].Length)
        {
            case 1:
                AR[i] = GetResults(Inputs, Outputs, Coefficients[i][0]);
                break;
            case 2:
                AR[i] = GetResults(Inputs, Outputs, Coefficients[i][0], Coefficients[i][1]);
                break;

            // Etc
        }                

    return AR;
}
```

Comment: I presume the methods behave differently depending on the number of parameters?

Comment: `switch` is nice and clean. If you need to stick with a single public method taking an array of arrays, there's no reason to change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the fact that you're using `Coefficients[i]` multiple times in the loop feels like a pain to me, to start with. The *first* refactoring I'd do would be:

```
// Names changed to fit .NET conventions
public AnalysisResult[] PerformAnalysis(int[][] coefficients)
{
    return Array.ConvertAll(coefficients, GetResult);
}

private AnalysisResult GetResult(int[] input)
{
    switch (input.Length)
    {
        case 1: return GetResult(input[0]);
        case 2: return GetResult(input[0], input[1]);
        case 3: return GetResult(input[0], input[1], input[2]);
        case 4: return GetResult(input[0], input[1], input[2], input[3]);
        case 5: return GetResult(input[0], input[1], input[2], input[3], input[4]);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number of inputs: " + input.Length);
    }
}
```

That's assuming you really want to keep separate methods for the different cases, which is the assumption in the question.

Comment: it would be easy in java, as JDK5 provides var args, called variable arguments. so your method could have been like private AnalysisResult GetResult(int... input)

Comment: @AKS: C# has the same ability - it would be `GetResult(params int[] input)`. But the OP *wants* to have separate methods for the different cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection if you like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Coefficients.Length; i++) {
    // Get all private methods named GetResults with a number of parameters equal to Cofficients[i].Length
    var methodToCall = this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Where(mi => mi.Name == "GetResults" && mi.GetParameters().Count() == Coefficients[i].Length);
    // Invoke that method via reflection
    AR[i] = methodToCall.Invoke(this, Cofficients[i]);
}
```